# Is using Silverlight a hindrance for Startups?

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, startup

I'm having a lot of difficulty choosing a web framework and/or programming language for an idea, and of the programming knowledge I have, I'm the best with Silverlight/.NET

The web app itself would be in Silverlight presuming I go this route. From what I've read Silverlight has around a 65% install base but would it still be a hindrance?

Please note it's essentially an entire website, and the targeted audience are Students, Teachers, and Hobbyists

Also is the reliance on Microsoft a bad thing or even relevant?

Comment: If it's a public-facing website, half of your users will need to install it. You'll have to decide for yourself if this will be a turnoff for your user base.  It's a simple install, but still...

Answer (score 2):

> From what I've read Silverlight has around a 65% install base but would it still be a hindrance?

It really depends.  If your target user is likely to be in that 65%, then no, there would be little or no hindrance.

If the target user is not in that 65%, or is the public at large, then it would depend on whether your application was compelling enough to convince the potential users in the 35% to install Silverlight.

This is a matter of balance on your part - try to measure the gain in productivity (from using the technology you know) vs. the cost of a different architecture and the cost of learning a new tech.

Also, remember, no technology has a 100% install base - even HTML.  It's amazing, but there are still a lot of people running archaic browsers out there who will miss out unless you use the most bare-bones HTML possible...

Comment: My target users are primarily students and teachers, and eventually would include hobbyists

Comment: @Indebi: Its difficult to know - most students, IMO, are willing (anxious?) to install new toys, so it's probably not a problem.  Most teachers and hobbyists will install something if they feel there is a valid reason to do so.  If your application is compelling, it probably would be fine in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Although your familiarity with Silverlight will allow you to develop the application quickly, Silverlight is not installed on a large number of traditional computers. Furthermore Silverlight is not going to be visible on the majority of phone platforms that are available (I believe WP7 supports Silverlight, but thats the extent of it). Here I'd also note that most mac users don't have silverlight installed (although it is available to them) and no linux users have Silverlight (although they have the Moonlight equivalent).

So if you are trying to reach as large an audience as possible, I'd go with a HTML based solution. I'd even avoid flash because flash applications do not work on iOS devices.

However if your application really does need capabilities that are beyond what HTML5 can provide, then development in Silverlight may not be a bad idea.

Comment: What is the combined installed base of HTML5 capable browsers?

Comment: To the full spec, I'm quite sure it's 0%, considering that the specification is still in development, and knowing how standards organizations work, I'm not expecting the spec to be completed till sometime in 2015+

Comment: For the mobile market I would write an app for them in MonoTouch and MonoDroid when the time comes

Comment: I'd agree with you there. However I'm not sure what kind of application the OP is developing. Is it something akin to a full fledged website, or is this more of an application. Hence the broad answer.

Comment: @Indebi - If its a full fledged website, I'd recommend against using Silverlight as the platform to develop it. Silverlight doesn't integrate very well with search engines, so your rankings in Google and other things will be low.

Comment: @Indebi - Additionally, Microsoft provides the ASP.Net libraries exactly for the purpose of building websites. Silverlight is billed as a solution to creating very rich user interfaces easily, but it's not the ideal platform with which to build websites (it can be done, just as a few websites are built in flash), but it's not idea. ASP.Net also would allow you to use your existing knowledge of the .Net libraries to your advantage. You also then have the option of using a CMS to help build the website.

Comment: Couldn't I just have the asp.net backend create HTML pages that are search engine friendly and contain the title and description of the content? And when that link is clicked it'll navigate to that content in the Silverlight application?

Comment: You could do that. But if the content is in the silverlight applicaiton, then none of that content will be in searchable, or linkable from other websites. The number of links are a major factor in determining your rankings. Maybe its possible to have something of that sort work, I for one have never tried it.

Comment: Also you seem quite well settled in the silverlight framework. Ultimately it will come down to a decision that only you can make. Is the time you save developing this application in silverlight, worth the possible loss of a percentage of the userbase, and the possible loss in search engine rankings? The second of those issues can probably be fixed with some clever engineering, but the time taken in doing that could just as well be spent on learning ASP.Net to design the site.